# Create SoftwareBitmap with Colorspace information

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I'm looking for a way to create a [`SoftwareBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.softwarebitmap?view=winrt-22621) from raw bitmap data (a [`SkBitmap`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/skia/include/+/72af3df3d4b492c5d84c11c7f38fcdbf67188fc1/core/SkBitmap.h) specifically) that has the color space information encoded in it (specifically it's in `sRGB` colorspace). None of the [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.softwarebitmap?view=winrt-22621#methods) to create a `SoftwareBitmap` have a [`ColorManagementMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.colormanagementmode?view=winrt-22621). I have looked at the [`BitmapDecoder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder?view=winrt-22621) class as well, specifically at its [`GetSoftwareBitmapAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.getsoftwarebitmapasync?view=winrt-22621#windows-graphics-imaging-bitmapdecoder-getsoftwarebitmapasync(windows-graphics-imaging-bitmappixelformat-windows-graphics-imaging-bitmapalphamode-windows-graphics-imaging-bitmaptransform-windows-graphics-imaging-exiforientationmode-windows-graphics-imaging-colormanagementmode)) method but that fails with the error of `Component not found` which *probably* makes senses since the buffer is already a raw buffer and there's nothing to really *decode* and thus it fails to find an appropriate codec from the list of [supported image formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder?view=winrt-22621#image-formats). Is there a way that I can ensure that the created bitmap respects the colorspace information?

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the raw data and how did you get that?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT It's a `SkBitmap` that's created using Skia library APIs. Does that help?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Do you have any pointers/suggestions on how this could be handled or is there a better/focussed forum where I can get this resolved?

Comment: I'm checking if there are any suggestions about this.

Comment: The only way to build a SoftwareBitmap with proper colorspace is to get pixels (bytes) of the (already converted to target color space) image and create the SoftwareBitmap from it using SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer. Using WinRT, that'd mean using BitmapDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync(..., ColorManageToSRgb). However you say your image is already sRGB which is the default colorspace in Windows, so in this case, you shouldn't need to convert colorspace. If it was ProPhoto RGB or Adobe RGB or scRGB, for example, then yes, you'd had to convert. It probably depends how you get the skBitmap thing

Comment: Actually GetPixelDataAsync w/o parameters uses ColorManageToSRgb implicitely, quoting the doc *"as a convenience, this method performs color management from the frame's embedded color space (if it exists) to the sRGB color space."*. So, if your input has a color space (different that default sRGB), using this plus SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've consulted the team about this. Based on the response I got, UWP doesn't appear to support color management at all. Using the decoder and pixel data doesn't work either and doesn't retain the color space even in an existing sRGB image. You might need to use Win32 or other method for color management of images.